# Django: How to Update Multiple Objects using forms

Tags: django, forms, model

I'm fairly new to Django and web design, just a quick question.
Is there a way in my views to generate a single form with all my Game objects I have already created and update both the attributes in the game class and possibly the team class as well as they are connected through the foreign keys? I've seen a lot about forms, model forms, and formsets everywhere online, but they seem to all update a single object.

Ideally what I would like to be able to have is one page with a form or a bunch of forms that when I input the scores of the games that happen that day it will update the game objects referring to the games that day as well as the corresponding teams objects. Not sure if this is possible or not.

These are my models below:

```
class Game(models.Model):
teamone = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True, related_name = 'teamone')
teamtwo = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True, related_name = 'teamtwo')
teamonegoals = models.IntegerField(null = True)
teamtwogoals = models.IntegerField(null = True)
gamedate = models.DateField(null = True)

class Team(models.Model):
position = models.IntegerField(null = True)
name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
played = models.IntegerField()
won = models.IntegerField()
drawn = models.IntegerField()
lost = models.IntegerField()
gf = models.IntegerField()
ga = models.IntegerField()
gd = models.IntegerField()
points = models.IntegerField()
curForm = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
```

From my views.py (trying to just update the games that happened today) i know this is really broken and doest work at all just trying to show what I have

```
def inputScores(request):

today = Game.objects.filter(gamedate = datetime.date.today())

GameForm = modelformset_factory(Game, fields = ('teamone','teamtwo','teamonegoals','teamtwogoals'))
#want to iterate through all the objects in today and have them on an update form
    #game = Game.objects.get(id = game.id)
    #form = GameForm()
        #if request.method == 'POST':
        #   form = GameForm(request.POST, instance = game.id)
            #if form.is_valid():
            #   form.save()
            #return redirect('/')
```

My forms.py

```
    from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *



class GameForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = '__all__'
```

My inputscores.html

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>InputScores</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "" method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for f in forms%}
            {{f}}
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}

        <input type = "submit" name = "Submit">
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]can you add a screenshot of the result of the above code....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>InputScores</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form  method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}

        <input type = "submit" name = "Submit">
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

check here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-based-generic-views-django-create-retrieve-update-delete/?

Try This